# Multiple counters started from the same function?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a piece of code that uses two input buttons to start functions updating a number of outputs, including those shown below.  However, I want the outputs to display the numbers as they cycle from their previous value to the updated one and was pointed towards the setInterval function previously - is it possible to make this work for multiple outputs?

I've tried to number my tempCounters to distinguish, but that doesn't seem to have worked - any help would be much appreciated!

html

```
<button onClick = "IncTHR()">Increase Throttle</button>
<button onClick = "DecTHR()">Decrease Throttle</button>
<input type="text" id="THR">

<div id="CoolantTemp1"></p>
<div id="CoolantTemp2"></p>
```

javascript

```
var CoolantTemp1 = 366;
var tempCounter1 = 366;
var CoolantTemp2 = 250;
var tempCounter2 = 250;
var Throttle = 5;
var ControlRodHeight = 50;
var PrimaryPump = 1;

function IncTHR(){
Throttle++;
if (Throttle > 10){
    Throttle = 10;
}
CoolantTemp1 = (220+(ControlRodHeight*2.2)+(PrimaryPump*20)+(Throttle*3.2));
update();

var incInt = setInterval(function() {
    if (tempCounter1 < CoolantTemp1){
        displayResults(tempCounter1);
        tempCounter1++;
    } else {
        displayResults(CoolantTemp1);
        tempCounter1 = CoolantTemp1;
        clearInterval(incInt);
    }
}, 500);

CoolantTemp2 = (190+(ControlRodHeight*2.2)+(PrimaryPump*22)-(Throttle*2.9));

var incInt = setInterval(function() {
    if (tempCounter2 < CoolantTemp2){
        displayResults(tempCounter2);
        tempCounter++;
    } else {
        displayResults(CoolantTemp2);
        tempCounter2 = CoolantTemp2;
        clearInterval(incInt);
    }
}, 500);
}

function DecTHR(){
Throttle--;
if (Throttle < 0){
    Throttle = 0;
}
CoolantTemp1 = (220+(ControlRodHeight*2.2)+(PrimaryPump*20)+(Throttle*3.2));
update();

var decInt = setInterval(function() {
    if (tempCounter1 > CoolantTemp1){
        displayResults(tempCounter);
        tempCounter--;
    } else {
        displayResults(CoolantTemp1);
        tempCounter1 = CoolantTemp1;
        clearInterval(decInt);
    }
}, 500);

CoolantTemp2 = (190+(ControlRodHeight*2.2)+(PrimaryPump*22)-(Throttle*2.9));

var decInt = setInterval(function() {
    if (tempCounter2 > CoolantTemp2){
        displayResults(tempCounter2);
        tempCounter--;
    } else {
        displayResults(CoolantTemp2);
        tempCounter2 = CoolantTemp2;
        clearInterval(decInt);
    }
}, 500);
}


function update() {
document.getElementById("THR").value = Throttle;
}

function displayResults(temp) {
document.getElementById("CoolantTemp1").innerHTML = "Coolant Temperature 1 is " + temp1;
document.getElementById("CoolantTemp2").innerHTML = "Coolant Temperature 2 is " + temp2;
}
```

Comment: You have duplicate declarations for `decInt` and `incInt`.

Comment: Also, within the function `DecTHR`, `tempCounter` is not defined.

Comment: I would recommend creating another function so you can pass in the parameters which you want to update. For example setting `CoolantTemp1` and `CoolantTemp2` would be a function call to determine it's value.

Comment: Once you have a working chuck of code (but feel it could be greatly improved), head over to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ where you can seek advice on refactoring. It is however recommended that you try to refactor it yourself as much as possible first. Try to understand why you might need to do this, i.e readability, performance, etc.

Comment: Thanks Matt - so pressing a Throttle button would then call a function to work out 'CoolantTemp1', and also call the function involving the counter in the example above?

Comment: Precisely, a separation of concerns. Each function should have a single responsibility, `calculateCoolantTemp` or `renderCoolantTemp`, this way your code is reusable and, in theory, much easier to maintain!

Answer (score 0):

It throws the error `temp1 is not defined` , also there is no `CoolantTemp2` element in your html. So you have to replace this:

```
  document.getElementById("CoolantTemp1").innerHTML = "Coolant Temperature 1 is " + temp1;
  document.getElementById("CoolantTemp2").innerHTML = "Coolant Temperature 2 is " + temp2;
```

with this:

```
  document.getElementById("CoolantTemp1").innerHTML = "Coolant Temperature 1 is " + CoolantTemp1;
  document.getElementById("CoolantTemper2").innerHTML = "Coolant Temperature 2 is " + CoolantTemp2;
```

Also each `<div>` should close with a `</div>`, like this:

```
<div id="CoolantTemp1"></div>
<div id="CoolantTemper2"></div>#
```

See demo-->http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/bWGOzP

Comment: Hi Theodore, thanks for your answer but unfortunately it only seems to update CoolantTemp1 output when I run this?

Comment: Apologies for all the typos! Thanks for pointing them out.  

Sorry to ask another question, but this now runs and gives me outputs which is great, thanks, but seems to have lost the counter function that I originally wanted? So now my answers are automatically updating to the final solution rather than displaying the integer values in between along the way.